# How to make two strings into a list in Python?

Tags: python

I have two strings I want to have in a list type:

```py
str1 = "select something from tbl"
str2 = "select somethingElse from tbl2"
```

I want this as my output:

```py
list = ['select something from tbl','select somethingElse from tbl2']
```

so I can pass each string into a for loop:

```py
for statement in list:
  #do something and it executes the statements passed
```

Here's additional context:

```
list = [soql_w_compoundedAttributes, soql_wo_compoundedAttributes]

for item in list:
  final_df = []
  print(item)
  df = spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.salesforce") \
       .option("login", "https://test.salesforce.com") \
       .option("username", user) \
       .option("password", pass) \
       .option("soql",item) \
       .load()
  final_df.append(df)
sfDF = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, final_df)
```

I get a REASON BAD REQUEST ERROR and when I look at my print(item) results i see that both sql statements are being passed at the same time. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: `myList = [str1, str2]`?

Comment: you answered your own question on line 4. what else are you looking for?

Comment: the issue is when i pass each item in this list into a spark dataframe creator, the item includes both sql statements resulting in bad request. I supposed perhaps list created isn't appropriate for this task.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error. Also please post the actual code you use, including any setup. We need a full working example to be able to help you. Please see this guide on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update your question.

Comment: Also just for your understanding, the reason you're getting downvotes is because your underlying problem seems to be the way you're calling spark, which is not indicated at all by the title or your initial post. If you really are having a problem creating a list, then it's certainly not evident in the code you've posted. Make sure that the code you post can be run by us, someone without your context, and that it reproduces the error or results you're asking about. Otherwise there's no way for us to tell what's going wrong in your code!

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
myList = [str1, str2]
```

Then:

```
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "select something from tbl"
str2 = "select somethingElse from tbl2"

list1 = [str1, str2]

for item in list1:
    #the rest of the code goes here
```